# Accessing a specific array

Tags: javascript

I have a set of arrays named in the following fashion: `question0, question1, question2` etc.
I also have a variable that corresponds to the question number.

With this, how would I access array `question0` without having to type out the whole name. For example, in a for loop, I have if the loop number is `5`, I want to do an operation on `question5`. I know this is really simple, but I haven't been able to find the solution.

Comment: it can be done with `eval` but it shouldn't.

Comment: Are you looking for [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have an array of arrays instead? Or a map?

Answer (score 2):

Variables ending in sequential numbers are usually a hint to use arrays. Sounds like you need an array of arrays instead, and then you can just:

```
doOperation(question[somenumber])
```

Comment: When I do an operation say: BigArray[0].push(object), and the array 'question0' is the object at BigArray[0], will the global question0 array be updated as well?

Comment: @MannyNarton: Yes. (But you probably shouldn’t need a global `question0` anymore...)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a big array, `question`, where each item it itself an array?

That aside, if the variables are global then you could use `window['question'+i]`, with `i` being the number of the question.

Comment: An array with in an array? No, We must go deeper!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use variable names with an ordinal number as their suffix; use the proper structures, such as an array:

```
var questions = ['why?', 'what?', 'where?'],
nr = 2; // the question number

alert(questions[nr]);
```

In my example, each "question" is a string, but it could be any other structure, including another array.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be simpler to have your question(n) values as an array. From there you could use the following: `questions[i]` where i represents the current loop number, thus improving manipulation.

```
var questions = [["What?", "Why?"], ["When?", "How?"]];
for(var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
 for(var j = 0; j < questions[i].length; j++) {
  console.info(questions[i][j]);
 }
}
```